# Shop by department in magento

Tags: php, magento

As shown in picture I want to show only Category in homepage instead of product.

For ex. I have 10 Categories & each category has 100 products!
So in homepage I am showing 5 products of each category.
I want to show only category name along with category picture. On clicking the picture it will take to Category Page where all products will be there.
How to do this?

[image]

Comment: Please explain what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use CMS page for this. Create a CMS page from the backend, there you can insert image and also create a widget to create the link to the category.

There is a button **Insert Widget**.There you can select the widget type as **catalog category links** and then selects the category.

Hope this will help.